# High loss on correct predictions, low loss on wrong predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to teach MobileNetV2 architecture a classification task and during training and validation everything was going well. The validation loss reached 0.1 (Categorical Cross-entropy) and accuracy was 99%. During testing though, even though accuracy didn't drop, loss blew up to 16! I checked the loss distribution across different predictions and, in my surprise, loss on correct predictions (99% of them) was 16 and loss on wrong predictions was ~4. As I am not experienced, I would like you to reference me to some of the probable causes of this behavior. If you would like me to post more specific information, please do not hesitate to tell me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, silly me used sigmoid instead of softmax as an activation function for the last layer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).